# Interaction Studio (Personalization): sendEvent to Personalization(IS) for every change on the Website dropdown

Tags: marketing-cloud, interaction-studio

We have a dropdown on the website with the below options

1. Patient
2. Doctor
3. Caregiver

We want to send this option as an attribute to Interaction Studio and update the particular attribute every time there is any change in the dropdown.

So below are the steps I followed

1. First I create an attribute with the name "howCanWeHelpType"
2. Wrote the below code to send the event from website and update the attribute

   ```
            SalesforceInteractions.listener("change", ".wizard__hat.userlist", (event) => {

                    let howCanWeHelpTypeString = event.target.value;

                    SalesforceInteractions.sendEvent({

                     interaction: { name: "How Can We Help Type Update" },

                            user: { attributes: { howCanWeHelpType: howCanWeHelpTypeString}},        

                    })

                }),

            ]
   ```

I am referring to document: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/personalization/guide/sitemap-implementation.html#interaction

**Issue**: On every change I can't see the attribute is updating.

Can someone help me to fix this? I am new to Interaction Studio.

Thanks for your help in advance